# How can I dynamically generate and display QML elements within a Popup window in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qml

I'm currently working on a PyQt5 application that incorporates QML. The application dynamically generates QML code from a configuration file (`configuration.yaml`). The generated QML code is then sent from Python to QML using signals, and I'm utilizing `Qt.createQmlObject()` to instantiate QML objects.

The challenge I'm encountering is that this process works seamlessly in the main application, but when attempting the same in a `Popup` element, the generated QML objects aren't visible on the application interface. Notably, no errors are thrown during execution. Despite verifying that the QML objects are successfully created through debugging, they do not appear on the interface.

Since `TestPopup.qml` is using `MainPopup.qml` as its parent and might be causing a problem. I've checked the `addElement()` function and it is working fine.

**Code:**

*MainPopup.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2

Popup {
    id: mainPopup
    
    ...

}
```

*TestPopup.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2

MainPopup {
    id: testPopup
    
    function addElement(elementId, elementString) {
        Qt.createQmlObject(elementString, testPopup, elementId)
    }
    
    ...

}
```

*app.py*

```
...

test_qml = """        
    import QtQuick 2.9
    import QtQuick.Window 2.2
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3    
            
    Text {
        text: "Hello World!"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
"""

test_popup = window.findChild(QObject, "testPopup")
test_popup.addElement("testID", test_qml)

...
```

Comment: Using a Loader to create and display the Popup could help solving your problem.

Comment: @JürgenLutz I have also tried that but the thing is I'm generating the QML in my python code and `Loader` was also showing some other errors. But I've managed to resolve it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77474798/how-can-i-dynamically-generate-and-display-qml-elements-within-a-popup-window-in/77495129#77495129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, I was trying to add an element in `testPopup` which was extending from `MainPopup` and was not visible on his own. I had to add the new element to `MainPopup`'s `contentItem` like this:

```
...

function addElement(elementId, elementString) {
    Qt.createQmlObject(elementString, testPopup.contentItem, elementId)
}

...
```